Hypothetical or past

"I'm not here because I have to be.  I could close up and leave here any time I wanted go wherever I wanted" says a woman, who lives in a town with only two people.

I don't understand why she use the past tense wanted.  Is she actually referring to the past or is the usage has something to do with "hypothetical"？

Yes, it's hypothetical. In effect she is saying "I'm staying here because don't want to leave. If I wanted to leave I could do so at any time."

I can understand this pattern.  Is the original a loose way of saying it,  or there is something I don't know and that sentence can be used as written language？

It has nothing to do with written-vice-spoken. It’s completely idiomatic and very common. Compare to the famously inaccurate assertion, “I could quit smoking any time I wanted to.”

"...or is there something I don't know?" I could leave here any time I wanted expects the listener/reader to understand if I wanted to leave. The previous sentence I'm not here because I have to be has already told us that she is not forced to stay.

@KateBunting  I notice you revised my sentence, thanks.  What about the last part "Is the ... , or is there something I don't know and that sentence can be used as written language". Or maybe "and can that sentence be..." I always have difficulties when deciding which sentence patterns to use.

We're getting into a new topic here, but, yes, the correct word order for questions is can that sentence be...? (A regular sentence can be used as a question if it is spoken in a certain tone of voice - "He is?" - but normal questions are in the form "Is he?").
